# Qt pop-up widget with a message

Tags: c++, qt

In a regular `QMainWindow`, I want to display a widget on the bottom of the window containing a simple error message, and after some time hide or destroy that image (I want a simple pop-up report/log widget).

What should I use? `QDialog`, `QWidget`? Is there any widget similar to what I want?

Comment: IMO this question is opinion based and it depends on your needs. Please specify your problem with more details, post some code, examples and point out the one real problem.

Comment: Why not to use `mainWindow->statusBar()->showMessage("my message", 1000);` to show a message on main window's status bar for 1 second? For more details look at `QStatusBar::showMessage()` function.

Answer (score 2):

A wrote a simple popup message box that shows some text and smoothly fades out after given amount of time. Looks like what you need. [Grab here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/37252679fde93b4e7dae0019d64c68e5)

```
NotifyMessageBox::showMessage(tr("Loading finished"), this);

NotifyMessageBox::showMessage(tr("Failed to load test results \"%1\": %2").arg(
                              docId, 
                              DocumentRequest::errorString(error)), 
                              QFont("Segoe UI", 12), 
                              1500, // time interval to destroy after
                              this);
```

Answer (score 0):

`QDialog` will create a new separate window to show your message. Some `QDialog` based widgets are readily available, e.g you can call `QMessageBox::information()` to show a simple text message.

Dialog can me modals or not, meaning they will (or not) block user interactions with the underlying window.

I you do not want to open a new window and want your popup to show in an existing window, you have to play with the way `QWidget` are drawn. In practice it means that your popup widget must be a direct child of your window widget (`QMainWindow`, etc.) and must be brought before its siblings using `QWidget::raise()`.